# Automake LIBADD not linking in

Tags: autotools, automake

I'm attempting to add ZMQ to c_icap.

This is my (which is modified from the stock makefile) Makefile.am:

```
pkglib_LTLIBRARIES=srv_bluvector_icap.la
    INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)

    srv_bluvector_icap_la_LIBADD = /usr/local/lib/libzmq.la

    srv_bluvector_icap_la_LIBADD = @MODULES_LIBADD@
    srv_bluvector_icap_la_CFLAGS=  -I../../include/
    srv_bluvector_icap_la_LDFLAGS= -module -avoid-version
    srv_bluvector_icap_la_SOURCES = srv_bluvector_icap.c

EXTRA_DIST= makefile.w32 srv_bluvector_icap.def
```

This is the output after I run make (after doing ./configure from the top level):

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../..           -I../../include/ -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MT srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.Tpo -c -o srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.lo `test -f 'srv_bluvector_icap.c' || echo './'`srv_bluvector_icap.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../include/ -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MT srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.Tpo -c srv_bluvector_icap.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.o
mv -f .deps/srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.Tpo .deps/srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -I../../include/ -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -module -avoid-version  -o srv_bluvector_icap.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/c_icap srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.lo  
libtool: link: gcc -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/srv_bluvector_icap.so -bundle  .libs/srv_bluvector_icap_la-srv_bluvector_icap.o    -O2  
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "srv_bluvector_icap.la" && ln -s "../srv_bluvector_icap.la" "srv_bluvector_icap.la" )
```

Which doesn't contain any zmq linking.

When I run the icap plugin, I get this:

```
Loading service :bluvector path srv_bluvector_icap.so
Found handler C_handler for service with extension:.so
Error loading module srv_bluvector_icap.so:dlopen(/usr/local/c-icap/lib/c_icap/srv_bluvector_icap.so, 10): Symbol not found: _zmq_connect
  Referenced from: /usr/local/c-icap/lib/c_icap/srv_bluvector_icap.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/c-icap/lib/c_icap/srv_bluvector_icap.so
Error while loading service srv_bluvector_icap.so
```

Which, I believe means that zmq didn't get linked in.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are overwriting the value of your `LIBADD` variable, by setting it twice:

```
srv_bluvector_icap_la_LIBADD = /usr/local/lib/libzmq.la
srv_bluvector_icap_la_LIBADD = @MODULES_LIBADD@
```

instead, you should do something like:

```
srv_bluvector_icap_la_LIBADD = /usr/local/lib/libzmq.la
srv_bluvector_icap_la_LIBADD+= @MODULES_LIBADD@
```